# What is the least valuable unit of actively used currency that is coined or printed?

Tags: currency, coins

Another [question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1676/ive-heard-pennies-are-being-phased-out-in-canada-is-this-true) about the potential for giving up on pennies made me wonder. What is the smallest (in terms of value) unit of currency that has a minted coin or printed bill that is in active use worldwide?

Also, what is the value of that denomination in US Currency?

Comment: Interesting question; of course it could change on a daily basis, depending on exchange rates.  If you include hyper-inflating economies like Zimbabwe, it might get harder still.

Comment: Zimbabwe's currency got so useless the government stopped bothering; everyone just uses other currencies (officially, the US dollar; also, the rand, pound, euro, and this one from Botswana called the pula).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of a currency may be different depending on what you use for a 'value'. For example, the Japanese Yen may have a different 'value' if you are comparing it against the Euro or the US Dollar, for example.

Believe it or not, the smallest unit of currency (in terms of value of US dollars) is the Vietnamese Dong, at a value of 0.00005 Dollars per Dong.

Maybe the Zimbabwean dollar is counted differently, maybe/

[moneycentral.msn.com](http://moneycentral.msn.com/investor/market/exchangerates.aspx?selRegion=1&selCurrency=1) has a cool currency converter which allows you to compare all current world currencies against a single currency, and presents it in a chart form.

Comment: Is there a one-dong coin, though? Or do they only mint things in the thousands and up?